# How to delete the Ionic image at launch on the browser application

Tags: image, ionic-framework, loading

I have an application realized with Ionic 5.2.3.
When loading page 'index.html' (example: refresh) an image try to display on the browser version.

Exemple project :

```
ionic start myApp tabs
cd myApp
ionic cordova build browser
```

Run your app on server and you see that : [Image problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i23K2.png)

It's same on this website making by Ionic : [Link problem example](https://mapsplugin.github.io/ionic-googlemaps-quickdemo-v4/home)

I wish :

- Either: delete it
- Or: replace it by the image 'myApp\resources\splash.png' which works very well in the Android version

  node -v 10.16.0
  cordova -v 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
  ionic -v 5.2.3

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: The images are clear, but what is this image? Where is it placed or how it came.. i've made like a month ago a browser app and there was no such image on it.. and its not a splash screen , its an overlay image so you need to clarify more..

Comment: This image is visible on any Ionic application, you can see it when the page loads. It is only visible in the browser version : ionic cordova build browser --prod

Comment: Nobody can help me ???

Comment: After some hours i'll try to see it for you but for now i have no computer to try for you.

Comment: I find it, thanks Mostafa ;)

Comment: Ah i'm sorry i completely forgot to reply to you. Am really sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding a solution.

You can remove the splashScreen and replace it with CSS, this removes this image at launch.

For create your CSS spashScreenn, see this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dPUmskG_-y0

Solved :)